# How do I preserve my custom Linq to SQL class changes?

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-2, orm

My MVC2 app use LINQ to SQL as the ORM.  I just drag and drop the tables from the SQL Server Explorer connection to the LINQ design surface.  Two of the tables (A and B) are related.  Table A has 3 foreign keys referencing Table B. In the LINQ design surface, I manually change the name of the parent property for these associations to give them more distinguished names.  However, whenever I modify the table structure in the SQL Server, and drag and drop the new structure to LINQ, I would lose the names.  Is there a way to prevent this from happening?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  When you drag the tables back to the designer, Linq to SQL regenerates the code in the partial class, obliterating your custom changes.

The only way to preserve the name change is to rename the affected table fields in the database.

You might be able to achieve such customization preservation with the [T4 Toolbox](http://www.olegsych.com/2009/05/t4-toolbox-linq-to-sql-schema-generator/).

Answer (score 0):

It is always a bad idea to make the associations at the LINQ level. Make the associations at the table level. This will ensure that when ever you are doing a drag and drop of the tables, the designer class reflects the correct associations.